# How to restore output from pg_dump into a new table name

Tags: postgresql, restore

I am dumping a large postgres table (~15m records) like this:

```
pg_dump -h myserver  -U my_user --table=mytable  -Fc -Z 9 --file mytable.dump mydb
```

The above creates a `mytable.dump` file. I now want to restore this dump into a new table called `mytable_restored`

How can I use the `pg_restore` command to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like the right tool for the job in the first place. Couldn't you just `COPY...TO`, then `COPY...FROM`?  or `insert into new_table select * from old_table`, if they are in the same database?

But given that you already have the dump file, the most straightforward way might be to load to a scratch database, rename the table, and retake the dump from there, then drop the scratch database.

Alternatively, you could use "pg_restore" without a "-d" option to dump the custom format file to a plain text dump file, then edit that file manually to change the name in each location it occurs.  Editing a file with 15 millions rows can be quite a chore, but it should be possible with something like "vi", or perhaps "sed" (but there you have to be careful not to change more than you intended to).